# GMail API TypeError: key must be a string, a buffer or an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, gmail-api

When i try to create any function with the google API in NextJS, it throws this error and i dont know what to do...

My Code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const gmail = google.gmail('v1');

const userId = 'me';

 export async function getGmailMessages(labelIds: string[], maxResults: number) {
   const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
     // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
     scopes: [
       'https://mail.google.com/',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
     ],
     keyFile: 'credentials.json',
   });
  

   // Acquire an auth client, and bind it to all future calls
   const authClient = await auth.getClient();
   google.options({auth: authClient});

   // Do the magic
   const mails = await gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: userId,
        labelIds: labelIds,
        maxResults: maxResults,
      })
    

      const array = mails.data.messages
      console.log(array)
      return array
```

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: key must be a string, a buffer or an object

Source
functions\gmailAPIInterface.tsx (23:44) @ eval

  21 | 
  22 | // Do the magic
> 23 | const mails = await gmail.users.messages.list({
     |                                         ^
  24 |      userId: userId,
  25 |      labelIds: labelIds,
  26 |      maxResults: maxResults,
```

When commenting out line 24 (the userid) it doesnt do this error  but it says its missing the required input 'userId'. I tried some things like reformatting and just rewriting but nothing helped.